# How do I test a PHP mail function without mailing to the actual addresses

Tags: php, email

Would I test this php script by creating a simple form on an HTML page and then pointing the action attribute to the .php file? I have created the .PHP file, just don't know how to send it off.

```
    <?php     

    $recipients = array('name@domain.com','name@domain.com',
    'name@domain.com',
    'name@domain.com',
    ); // i will be inserting the test email here


// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables

$name = $_POST['sender_name'];

$mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];

$mail_to = $_POST[$recipients];

$message = $_POST['sender_message'];


// Construct email subject

$subject = 'College Newsletter: ' . $name;


// Construct email body

$body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;



// Construct email headers

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail(implode(',',$mail_to), $subject, $body_message, $headers);

?>
```

The server doesn't seem to like my implode method. (SEE ABOVE) I kept getting the error: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in so
I changed the PHP to this:

```
    <?php     

    $to = array('name@domain.com','name@yahoo.com');
    // specify your email here


    // Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $mail_from = $_POST['mail'];

    $message = $_POST['message'];


    // Construct email subject

    $subject = 'Breaking News: ' . $name;


    // Construct email body

    $body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

    $body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

    $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;



    // Construct email headers

    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $name, $mail_from, $message, $headers);

    ?>
```

Now i get the error:
       Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in bulk_mailer_test.php on line 70
Anyone? 
-Cheers,-qs

Comment: mail yourself?? not really sure what you wanting here

Comment: So, is all i need to do that just a form with action attribute that points to the .php file? -Thanks -qs Or do I need to have WAMP or MAMP installed? -Sorry I'm new to the server-side. Thanks!

Comment: yes - a form action to that file, appropriately named fields, method ="post" etc. and yes you need a server of some sort if you expect to run your php through the web server

Comment: Actually, success from the `mail()` function only means PHP handed the mail off to the mail server.  Testing the return value of this function only gets you half way.  You will still want to try sending to an actual email address to confirm things come out the other side like you want.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand you correctly; in Dreamweaver I would need to set my site up as a testing server in order to send this?

Comment: @querystring you can setup an obscure domain for website production very cheaply and use that to test, its what a lot of people do, one.com gives you a domain of your choice and hosting for a whole year for £10.80 for example

Comment: @Parody - I am using a testing server with this file and I am getting the following error message: Warning: Illegal offset type in bulk_mailer_test.php on line 51. Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in bulk_mailer_test.php on line 77

Comment: @querystring i just ran your code and sent myself emails to 2 different email addresses without any problem? i just changed the email addresses and the `$_POST` values to a simple text string but that was all? so im guessing thats where your problem is

Comment: @Parody - So I guess the question becomes: What text string to insert within single quotes after $_POST - Thank You BTW for running that code. Also, what is wrong with this line   - Thanks!                            'mail(implode(',', $to), $name, $email, $message, $headers);'

Comment: Just updated my code with some changes I made to the PHP. Still can't get this to work. Latest error thrown:                                                                                                                                          **Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in bulk_mailer_test.php on line 70**

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this code

```
<?php     

$recipients = array('name@domain.com','name@domain.com',
'name@domain.com',
'name@domain.com',
); // i will be inserting the test email here

$mail_to = $_POST[$recipients];

$mail_sent = mail(implode(',',$mail_to)...
```

implode() wants an array. You're passing it a probably null value.

remove this `$mail_to = $_POST[$recipients];` and just use `mail(implode(',',$recipients)`

$_POST is a superglobal to collect data from a submitted form. If you have listed your recipient addresses in an array.. then there is no need for one. If you want to collect multiple emails from the form, then do something like this...

```
$recipients = array($_POST['email_1'], $_POST['email_2'], $_POST['email_3'], $_POST['email_4'],
);
```